# How to create Docker Image based on EC2 AMI image?

Tags: linux, image, docker, amazon-ec2

I installed several things on my CentOS EC2 instance (Java, MySql, gradle, setup local application...).

Also recently created EC2 AMI image out of all that.

Is it possible to create a Docker image directly from AMI image or what is the best way to do it?

(I just want to have all installations, java, app, setups inside a Docker image with minimal docker tuning/setup/troubleshooting, do not care how is done - either from AMI image or from some of the folders inside EC2)..

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: [Cross](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/432954/how-to-create-docker-image-based-on-ec2-ami-image)-[site](https://superuser.com/questions/1306980/how-to-create-docker-image-based-on-ec2-ami-image) spamming is generally frowned upon.